# null is not an object (evaluating 'RNPushNotification.getInitialNotification')

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use react native push notification in expo app so without eject the project. I'm facing a problem :

localNotification.js:

```
import PushNotification, {Importance} from 'react-native-push-notification';
export const handlerSystemNotification = () => {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
        channelId: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
        channelName: 'test app',
        autoCancel: true,
        bigText: 'body text notifiaction',
        subText: '',
        title: '⏳ Reminder',
        message: 'lorem txt...',
        playSound: true,
        soundName: 'default',
        importance: 10,
        vibrate: true,
        vibration: 1000,
        importance: Importance.HIGH,
        priority: "high",

    })
}
```

App.js:

```
useEffect(() => {

  PushNotification.configure({

    onRegister: function(token) {
        console.log("TOKEN:", token);
      },
    
      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
    
        // process the notification here
    
        // required on iOS only 
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      },
      
      // Android only
      senderID: "1090501687137",
      // iOS only
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
      },
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true
    });

  // Assume a message-notification contains a "type" property in the data payload of the screen to open
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log("Message handled in the background!", remoteMessage);
})

const unsub = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage=>{
  Alert.alert('A new FCM msg arrived', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage))
  console.log(remoteMessage);

  registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setExpoPushToken(token));

  return unsub;
})

}, []); 

const onPress= () => {
    handlerSystemNotification()

  }
```

Error :

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
> 'RNPushNotification.getInitialNotification')
>
> This error is located at: in App (created by ExpoRoot) in ExpoRoot in
> RCTView (created by View) in View (created by AppContainer) in RCTView
> (created by View) in View (created by AppContainer) in AppContainer in
> main(RootComponent)